alternative to unstable scan_pyarrow_dataset()?
We are new to polars and pyarrow, and we are trying to work with a pyarrow Dataset of .csv (and possibly other) file formats. We are using pyarrow to create the dataset because it supports partitioning of .csv files, whereas I believe polars.scan_csv() does not. scan_pyarrow_dataset() works fine (we're using polars 1.9.0) but we are concerned about depending on this function due to the warning here :

This functionality is considered unstable. It may be changed at any
point without it being considered a breaking change.

Our question: Why is this warning there, and is there another way to recursively scan directories for .csv files that are paritioned? Someone suggested we use pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.to_table(), but it reads the entire dataset into memory. Thank you!

It seems scan_pyarrow_dataset calls Dataset.to_table() - As for "unstable", there is a general overview: https://docs.pola.rs/development/versioning/#unstable-functionality - If you can choose the format, the docs also suggest parquet. "This method can only can push down predicates that are allowed by PyArrow (e.g. not the full Polars API). If scan_parquet() works for your source, you should use that instead."

If you want to avoid materializing the entire dataset (as pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.to_table() does), you could instead iterate over the Dataset in batches with the to_batches() method.
To make this work best, I think you would want to have PyArrow apply any filters that take advantage of the partitioning keys in your dataset and then pass the remainder off to Polars with Polars' from-arrow().
Here's an example using nyc-taxi dataset which is partitioned by (1) year and (2) month. We note that the Dataset object gets filtered so as little data has to be read from disk as possible:
import polars as pl
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import pyarrow.compute as pc

taxi = ds.dataset("nyc-taxi", partitioning="hive")

for batch in taxi.filter((pc.field("year") == 2019) & (pc.field("month") == 1)).to_batches():
    df = pl.from_arrow(batch)

    # Do the work you want to do with Polars. Here we just print:
    print(df.filter(pl.col("tip_amount") > 0.2 * pl.col("total_amount")))

